# Compare and process booleans in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, loops

The problem I'm having is that I have an array couple of identical objects that looks something like:

```
[
    {
        error:null,
        permissions:{ 
            perm1:false,
            perm2:true,
            perm3:false,
            etc...
        }
    },
    {
        error:null,
        permissions:{ 
            perm1:true,
            perm2:false,
            perm3:false,
            etc...
        }
    },
    {
        error:null,
        permissions:{ 
            perm1:false,
            perm2:false,
            perm3:false,
            etc...
        }
    },
    etc..
]
```

I need to do is "add" all of them together and get something like:

```
{
    error:null,
    permissions:{ 
        perm1:true,
        perm2:true,
        perm3:false,
        etc...
    }
}
```

I though up of this code:

```
var newObj = {};

for(myObject in objectArray){
    for(var [key, value] of Object.entries(myObject)){
        newObj[key] = (newObj[key] === true ? true : value)
    }
}

return newObj;
```

But that doesn't seem really efficient (or like it would work...), and I need the most efficient and fast method. If you could point me in the right direction, or link me to a question that might help me.

Comment: What about the `error`, will it always be `null`, or what would you want the new object to have there?

Comment: biggest issue is that i get those objects from another function, that contacts and API to get the data if any of those fail, the error gets stored there, meaning if the error !== null we should exit, and just return the error. EDIT: actually now thinking about it, we can just ignore that. the new object does not need it, as i do a couple of checks on the objects before they get thrown into the array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys in all objects are the same, you can take an array of one of the objects' keys, then iterate over each key and identify whether it should be true or false by checking whether `.some` of the objects have true for it:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        error:null,
        permissions:{ 
            perm1:false,
            perm2:true,
            perm3:false,
        }
    },
    {
        error:null,
        permissions:{ 
            perm1:true,
            perm2:false,
            perm3:false,
        }
    },
    {
        error:null,
        permissions:{ 
            perm1:false,
            perm2:false,
            perm3:false,
        }
    },
];
const errorObj = arr.find(({ error }) => error);
if (errorObj) {
  throw new Error(errorObj.error);
}
const keys = Object.keys(arr[0].permissions);
const permissions = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(
  key => [key, arr.some(({ permissions }) => permissions[key])]
));
console.log({ error: null, permissions });
```

There are some optimizations that might be make that might be worthwhile in some circumstances, but this is fundamentally an `O(n^2)` operation regardless, and the most important thing to do is to short-circuit a property to `true` when a match is found, rather than continuing through the rest of the array, which the `.some` accomplishes.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```js
var objectArray=[
    {
        error:null,
        permissions:{ 
            perm1:false,
            perm2:true,
            perm3:false
        }
    },
    {
        error:null,
        permissions:{ 
            perm1:true,
            perm2:false,
            perm3:false
        }
    },
    {
        error:null,
        permissions:{ 
            perm1:false,
            perm2:false,
            perm3:false
        }
    }
]


var newObj = null;

for(myObject in objectArray){
    let x=objectArray[myObject]
    if(newObj===null){
      newObj=x;
    }else{
      Object.keys(x.permissions).map(i=>{
         if(!newObj.permissions[i]){
          newObj.permissions[i]=x.permissions[i];
         }
      })
    }
}

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.reduce()` with the first object in your array as the accumulator. For each object in your array you can loop though the keys in your accumulator's permissions and change its `true`/`false` value based on whether the current object's value is `true`:

```js
const arr = [{ error: null, permissions: { perm1: false, perm2: true, perm3: false, } }, { error: null, permissions: { perm1: true, perm2: false, perm3: false, } }, { error: null, permissions: { perm1: false, perm2: false, perm3: false, } } ];

const [{error, permissions: p}] = arr;
const res = arr.reduce((acc, {permissions}) => {
  for(const key in acc.permissions)
    acc.permissions[key] = acc.permissions[key] || permissions[key];
  return acc;
}, {error, permissions: {...p}});

console.log(res);
```